# Automatically fill multi-page forms in chrome extension

Tags: forms, google-chrome, automation, fill

I'm working on a cross-pages webform autofill project. Now I can use popup to get data produced by background.js, and then send message to content.js to fill the first page form. However, when progrmatically clicked the "save and continue" button to another page, nothing happened.

Anyone has some ideas about what happened after the click and how to work it out. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Did you achieve this?